# Display Modal Form before sign-out action when sign-out button is clicked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Good day all. I am working on a Laravel application. I would like a modal(asking for a rating) to pop up when the user clicks sign out before the sign out procedure occurs.  The modal is held in a blade php file. Is there a way to achieve this?

This is the area of code that handles the sign/sub out

```
<form action="{{url('company/sub-subbedout/'.$sub->time_logger->id)}}" immethod="post">
       @csrf
       @method('PUT')
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Sub Out {{$sub->user->user_profile->first_name or ''}}</button>
</form>
```

I am expecting that after the button is clicked, the modal will appear asking for a rating. After the modal is closed/dismissed, the sign/sub out process continues.

Comment: diasble the form submission with javascript, then proceed with the form submission when something is selected

Comment: so what you are saying is. When the sub out button is clicked, the modal should be called then after rating or closing the form is submitted?

Comment: Yes you can do this simply with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="logout_form" action="{{url('/logout')}}" method="POST">
       @csrf
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Logout</button>
</form>
```

In js:

```
$(document).find('#logout_form').submit(function(){
     var isConfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?");

     if(isConfirm){
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
});
```